# How to enable jQuery validation localization in Razor file (ASP .NET MVC 5, jquery-globalize v. 1.2.2)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, localization, globalization

I would like to know how to enable validation localization for jQuery for example according to sample at [Docs Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) at the and of article?

Crossposted at https://forums.asp.net/p/2119555/6130560.aspx?p=True&t=636274881674960601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the packages:

1. Install-Package jquery-globalize;
2. Install-Package jquery.validation.globalize;

Them add the references at the following order:

1. jquery.validate.js;
2. jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js;
3. globalize/globalize.js;
4. jquery.validate.globalize.js.

Comment: Okay. Thanks but probably there should be invoked the correct locale-language through JavaScript, shouldn't be?

Comment: The packages I'm referring to are nuget packeges, so you should run on the nuget console. And js files, as you are working with MVC, you could add dynamically, by using a bundle, or manually in the HTML.

Comment: Okay, I have had mistake in markup. Now it is working except for decimal type property annotated with Range and DataType.Currency which is not validate at client scripting side.

Comment: does not find such files after installation

Comment: Did you run it inside `Package Manager Console`? Make sure you selected the web project option on the `Default Project` dropdown. It should be added to the scripts folder.